# Сохранения Presenter в MVP при скрытом уничтожении приложения

Tags: android, mvp, activity-life-cycle

В приложении под Андроид возникла следующая проблема (в приложении использую архитектуру MVP): при переключении с моего приложения на другое приложение, потребляющее много ресурсов, а потом обратно в свое приложение, все поля **Activity** стираются в том числе и уничтожается мой **Presenter**.

Для сохранения **Presenter** Пробовал использовать

1) `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance`,

2) поле `static`  для объекта **Presenter**

3) а также **fragment** для сохранения экземпляра **Presenter**

Но ни один из вышеперечисленных методов в данной ситуации мне не помог. Хотя например если их использовать при смене конфигурации (изменение ориентации экрана), все вышеперечисленные методы работают исправно.

Я предполагаю, что неработоспособность вышеперечисленных методов связана с тем что при переключении на другое приложение, происходит резкая нехватка ресурсов и андроид уничтожает мое приложении (kill app). Хотя метод `onDestroy` при переключении с одного приложения на другое в моем приложении не вызывается.

Можно ли в моем случае как то решить данную ситуацию ?
В идеале нужно сохранить объект **Presenter** так чтобы при уничтожении приложения можно было его возвратить, тут  хорошо подходит **shared preference** но он работает только с примитивными объектами, **presenter** в данном случае с помощью него невозможно сохранить.

---

Попытка сохранить `Presenter` во внешнем файле не увенчалась успехом. 
Несмотря на то, что как `Preseneter`, так и `ExperimentObject` внутри него реализуют интерфейс `Serializable`.

Activity:

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainView`
{

```
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";


private MainPresenter mMainPresenter;



private TextView mTextView_ShowVal;

private Button mButton_IncreaseVal;

private EditText mEditText_SetNum;

private Button mButton_SetEditTextVal;




private TextView mTextViewSomeText;






@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    Log.d(TAG, "ON CREATE");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    bindXML();





    read();


    if (mMainPresenter == null)
    {
        mMainPresenter = new MainPresenterImpl(this);
    }
    else
    {
        mMainPresenter.setNewViewObj(this);
    }


    mMainPresenter.onCreate();




    setListeners();





}


public void read(){
    Log.d(TAG, "read()");
    ObjectInputStream input;
    String filename = "testFilemost.srl";

    try {
        input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(new File(getFilesDir(),"")+File.separator+filename)));
        mMainPresenter = (MainPresenter) input.readObject();

        input.close();
    } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}



public void write(){
    Log.d(TAG, "write()");
    String filename = "testFilemost.srl";
    ObjectOutput out = null;



    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(getFilesDir(),"")+File.separator+filename));
        out.writeObject(mMainPresenter);
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "ON PAUSE");

    write();
    mMainPresenter = null;
    read();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "ON START");

    read();

    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "ON STOP");





    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "ON DESTROY");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "ON RESUME");

    mMainPresenter.onResume();

    super.onResume();
}











@Override
public String getTextEditText()
{
    return mEditText_SetNum.getText().toString();
}

@Override
public void setTextTextView(String text)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "text = " + text);
    mTextView_ShowVal.setText(text);
}












public void setListeners()
{
    mButton_IncreaseVal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
          mMainPresenter.executeClickIncreaseBtn();
        }
    });




    mButton_SetEditTextVal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
           mMainPresenter.executeClickSetValBtn();
        }
    });
}





public void bindXML()
{
    mTextView_ShowVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_ShowNum);
    mButton_IncreaseVal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_IncreaseNum);
    mEditText_SetNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_SetNum);
    mButton_SetEditTextVal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_SetEditTextVal);

    mTextViewSomeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.someText);
}



}
```

Presenter:

```
 public class MainPresenterImpl implements MainPresenter, Serializable
 {


private static final String TAG = "MainPresenterImpl";



private MainView mMainView;
private ExperimentObject mValueObject = new ExperimentObject(0);



public MainPresenterImpl(MainActivity mainActivity)
{
    mMainView = mainActivity;
}




@Override
public void onCreate()
{

}


@Override
public void onResume()
{

}


@Override
public void setNewViewObj(MainView newViewObj)
{
    mMainView = newViewObj;
    mMainView.setTextTextView(Integer.toString(mValueObject.getValue()));
}

@Override
public void executeClickIncreaseBtn()
{
    mValueObject.setValue( mValueObject.getValue() + 1 );
    mMainView.setTextTextView(Integer.toString(mValueObject.getValue()));
}

@Override
public void executeClickSetValBtn()
{
    String valueStr = mMainView.getTextEditText().toString();
    int value =  Integer.parseInt(valueStr);
    mValueObject.setValue(value);
    mMainView.setTextTextView(valueStr);
}
}
```

Comment: насколько мне известно вызов `onDestroy` не гарантирован, пользуйте `onStop`

Comment: @ermak0ff, спасибо, да согласен с вами `onStop` вызывается гарантированно.

Comment: Вы сами пишете, что не хватает ресурсов, вот и телефон выгружает их из памяти.  В таком случае `presenter` никак не сохранить

Comment: @pavel163, а в файле его нельзя как нибудь сохранить. Я вот пробовал (описал в вопросе),  но пока безрезультатно. Возможно я что-то ни так делаю.

Comment: У вас тут также MainView присутствует. Это активити, а активити не сериализуемая. презентер тоже значит не сериализуется

Comment: @pavel163, спасибо большое за подсказку. Обозначил поле с `MainView` как `transient` и все начало сохраняться. Даже когда я искусственно нажимаю на уничтожение приложения (_Terminate Application_) `Presenter` сохраняется и возвращает свое значение. Еще пришлось сделать поле `MainView` `static` т.к. без статического поля листенер ссылался на старый `Presenter` а у него объект `MainView = null` .

Answer (score 1):

Проблема не серализуемости `Presenter` была связана с тем что view объект не сериализуем (спасибо большое за подсказку, **@pavel163**). Обозначив его как `transient`, мой `Presenter` наконец начал сохранятся при любых обстоятельствах.

`Activity` осталось таким же его я приводить не буду. А `Presenter` изменился поле `MainView` пришлось сделать статическим, иначе листенеры буду ссылаться на старый `Presenter` в котором объект `MainView = null`  что выведет ошибку при его использовании.

В результате `Presenter` получился таким:

```
public class MainPresenterImpl implements MainPresenter, Serializable
{


private static final String TAG = "MainPresenterImpl";



private static transient MainView mMainView;
private ExperimentObject mValueObject;



public MainPresenterImpl(MainActivity mainActivity)
{

    mMainView = mainActivity;

    mValueObject = new ExperimentObject(0);
}




@Override
public void onCreate()
{

}


@Override
public void onResume()
{

}


@Override
public void setNewViewObj(MainActivity newViewObj)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "setNewViewObj");

    mMainView = newViewObj;
    mMainView.setTextTextView(Integer.toString(mValueObject.getValue()));
}

@Override
public void executeClickIncreaseBtn()
{
    mValueObject.setValue( mValueObject.getValue() + 1 );
    mMainView.setTextTextView(Integer.toString(mValueObject.getValue()));
}

@Override
public void executeClickSetValBtn()
{
    String valueStr = mMainView.getTextEditText().toString();
    int value =  Integer.parseInt(valueStr);
    mValueObject.setValue(value);
    mMainView.setTextTextView(valueStr);
}


}
```